# Rotating Image with position Fixed changing dynamically origin of rotation in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image-rotation

I'm trying to rotate an image with position:fixed as I scroll down the page, in my ReactJS application. I can make it rotate, only thing is that when I change my origin point, it does so with respect to the initially positioned image, and not the moved one (that changed rotation after I scrolled down the page).

----IMPORTANT----
I've added this Pen so that you can see the problem more clearly

### https://codepen.io/niccol-diana/pen/vYBJaed

In the code is my latest attempt to fix it (that clearly did not work).

```
state = {
    yIndex:0
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}


handleScroll = (event) => {
    let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    let itemTranslate = scrollTop/50;
    this.setState({yIndex:itemTranslate})
}


render () {

    let deviceHeight = window.screen.height;

    let rotateStyle = "";
    let rotateOrigin = "";

    if (this.state.yIndex < 20){
        rotateStyle = `rotate(${this.state.yIndex}deg)`;
        rotateOrigin = 'left top';
    }
    else if (this.state.yIndex >= 20 && this.state.yIndex < 40) {
        rotateStyle = `rotate(${20}deg)`
        let adjustedValue = this.state.yIndex - 20;
        console.log('adjustedValue:   '+ adjustedValue);
        rotateOrigin = 'right top';
        rotateStyle = `rotate(${adjustedValue}deg)`;
    }
}
```

RELEVANT CSS

```
.BluePowder {
position: fixed;
top:0;

height:100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

RELEVANT HTML (JSX)

```
<img style={{transform: rotateStyle, transformOrigin: rotateOrigin}} 
                className={classes.BluePowder} 
                src={bluePowder} 
                alt='BackgroundImage' />
```

Comment: Did you try position absolute? and you can wrap it in a div position relative, and play with the position. If you have an example like in codepen it will be nice.

Comment: ---- UPDATE ---- I'm inserting a commented Pen so that everyone can see the problem more clearly